# Changing stylesheet via radio button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a radio button which will change the theme (color) of my website based on the CSS file loaded.
I want it to show the changes live and the submit button is for saving the changes later.

HTML (Head)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="siteTheme" href="/sitefiles/theme/light.css">
```

HTML (Body)

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h2>Shading</h2>
      <div style="margin-bottom: 1px;">
        <input type="radio" name="colorscheme" id="1" value="1">
        <label>Light</label>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom: 1px;">
        <input type="radio" name="colorscheme" id="2" value="2">
        <label>Dark</label>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom: 1px;">
        <input type="radio" name="colorscheme" id="3" value="3">
        <label>Fairy</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <br/>
        <center>
          <span><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit"></span>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
var checkedButton1 = document.getElementById('1');
var checkedButton2 = document.getElementById('2');
var checkedButton3 = document.getElementById('3');
var light = "/sitefiles/theme/light.css";
var dark = "/sitefiles/theme/dark.css";
var fairy = "/sitefiles/theme/fairy.css";

checkedButton1.onclick = document.getElementById("siteTheme").setAttribute('href', light.value);
checkedButton2.onclick = document.getElementById("siteTheme").setAttribute('href', dark.value);
checkedButton3.onclick = document.getElementById("siteTheme").setAttribute('href', fairy.value);
```

I am getting no reaction from the button clicks and it's actually 'unloading' the template from the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign functions to the onclick properties. Note also that strings do not have a value property.

```
checkedButton1.onclick = ()=> document.getElementById("siteTheme").setAttribute('href', light);
checkedButton2.onclick = ()=> document.getElementById("siteTheme").setAttribute('href', dark);
checkedButton3.onclick = ()=> document.getElementById("siteTheme").setAttribute('href', fairy);
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be changing the stylesheet. I can link you to the example page: https://wayaupets.com/themeedit.php

Comment: @EarlGrey Use this code instead: https://jsfiddle.net/v30d1Lfx/

Comment: Hmm, I've replaced the code with that however still no change on the stylesheet. Is it just not communicating with the ID or the stylesheet for some reason? :/

Comment: @EarlGrey Have you tried putting the code inside `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Ahh, Perfect, Thank you for your help!

Comment: @EarlGrey No problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to pass it in function

```
var checkedButton1 = document.getElementById('1');
checkedButton1.onclick = ()=>{
  document.getElementById("siteTheme").href = light.value;
}
```